# asp.net check if url exists before opening popup

Tags: asp.net

Currently I have the following code that is run on ButtonClick:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", 
"window.open('" + DocumentData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["WebAddress"].ToString() 
                + "','_blank');", true);
```

It opens popup window with given link from DataBase (usually it is a link to document or image or video).
But I need to modify code a bit and I do not know which methods should I use:

1) I need to check if url really exists (if URL is responsive) and if not do not open popup, but show some message. Here I do not know how to check if Url exists? For example, if url is something like www.thesitedoesntexists.com then Do not load popup.

2) If url is in format www.yahoo.com instead of http://www.yahoo.com or https://someurl.com then above doesn't work.

If my web application is `www.myapplication.com` then in above scenario system opens url `www.myapplication.com/www.yahoo.com` instead of `www.yahoo.com`. How to deal with it? It could be somehow related with question #1. And this is the main problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code (untested) should accomplish these tasks:

1. Will verify that the url is defined
2. Will ensure it beings with http:// or https://
3. Will verify through an HttpRequest that the URL exists
4. Will show either a popup window with the URL loaded, or a warning alert if the URL is undefined or doesn't exist.

Button click handler code:

```
string url = DocumentData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["WebAddress"].ToString();
string script;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
{
    // prepend http to url if it isn't there.
    if(!url.ToLower().StartsWith("http://") || !url.ToLower().StartsWith("https://"))
    {
        url = "http://" + url;
    }

    // verify URL exists:
    if (UrlExists(url))
    {
        script = "window.open('" + url  + "','_blank');";   
    }
    else
    {
        script = "alert('URL does not exist')";
    }
}
else
{
    script = "alert('No URL specified!')";
}

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "WindowScript", script, true);
```

and define the following URL check method in your class:

```
public static bool UrlExists(string url)
{
   try
   {
      var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
      if (request == null) return false;
      request.Method = "HEAD";
      using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
      {
         return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
      }
   }
   catch (UriFormatException)
   {
      //Invalid Url
      return false;
   }
   catch (WebException)
   {
      //Unable to access url
      return false;
   }
}
```

I give full credit to the UrlExists method to: 
http://paigecsharp.blogspot.ca/2011/01/verify-url-exists.html

Comment: This doesn't solve real problem. Link could be an incorrect (doesn't exist) like www.test.com -> I do now need to open it. Also this doesn't solve my second problem that is the main one.

Comment: @renathy you need to define 'exist' first of all. I assumed you meant it's defined. Are you asking that the code check if the site exists? I.e. verify through an HTTP request?

Comment: I do not know how to verify it, but I really need to know if site exists (if url is responding) and my second problem is my main problem.

Comment: This almost work (I have changed || to &&), but if I do have ftp or some other prefix instead of http or https? I mean are there limited prefixes?

Comment: @renathy the above is expecting HTTP addresses based on your question. If you want other protocols you would need to enhance the UrlExists method to support them and also modify the code. Right now an ftp:// address would end up with `http://ftp://myaddress.com` because the code is looking for http(s) only.