# Determine validity of URL without firing page if valid?

Tags: c#, http, url

I want to determine if a URL is valid *without firing the server response of returning the page* if it is. (ie: without consuming the web page).

[I've found this very clever attempt but it doesn't seem to work at least on an MVC action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924679/c-sharp-how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-is-valid) without firing the action itself (which, incidentally, uses Selenium WebDriver and starts a FirefoxDriver instance which is how I know that the page is being consumed.)

Is there a way to say "Hey, server, I don't want the page but does it exist?" without the server actually trying to hand back the page?

Comment: I did say that the page to test is inside an MVC site. The calling code technology is 100% irrelevant as I can implement it any way necessary.

Comment: Sorry didn't get your question til now, did you try using `UrlExists()`? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957295/asp-net-check-if-url-exists-before-opening-popup) out.

Comment: Can't you just return an empty response? I don't think I completely understand this. The server is going to have to return something for you to know if the url is valid.

Comment: No, you cannot control from outside how the server will process your request (with HEAD or not) and the only way to know if an URL is valid is to make a request to that URL

Answer (score 1):

You can send the http "HEAD" command (instead of "GET", "POST", etc...) to just return the page headers.  The server should return a 200 if the page exists, and a 404 if it doesn't.

Something like this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = 
             new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, 
                                    new Uri("http://www.google.com"));

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. It's still causing the Controller to fire off the action. Interesting approach, however.

Comment: You could try the OPTIONS or TRACE verbs.